# Mongod service doesn't start with enableEncryption: true option in mongod.conf

Tags: configuration, services, mongodb

According to «[Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security-options)» manual, the MongoDB security options have a boolean parameter `enableEncryption`. I paid attention that the service `mongod` of MongoDB 3.2.4 is failed to start if the parameter `enableEncryption: true` is set. once I remove this parameter the service starts correctly.

**My question:**

- Is there any reason why the security parameter `enableEncryption: true` prevents from the service `mongod` to start?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Some error logs would be helpful. But just for started - have you configured your key/cert properly?

Comment: @Jacek, actually not. I didn't provide any key configuration. Is it mandatory?

Comment: Yes - unless Mongo uses some defaults, but I guess it doesn't. Have a quick look at this one: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-encryption/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameter allows you to enable encryption in the WiredTiger storage engine, but you still need to actually configure it.  You also need to be running the [Enterprise](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#enterprise) version of MongoDB, this is not available in the community/open source version.  Relevant snippets from [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.enableEncryption):

> - Enables encryption for the WiredTiger storage engine. You must set to true to pass in encryption keys and configurations.
> - Available in MongoDB Enterprise only.

Once you have the above done you have to actually configure keys (and manage them) as per [these docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/core/security-encryption-at-rest/#encryption-process).  Key generation and management is a complex topic, beyond the scope of this answer, but generally unless you really need at-rest encryption (and most do not) it's usually not worth the effort.